# Method for finding the xpath element/locator that increments - creating multiple transactions

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework

Robotframework-Selenium-PYTHON

Good day!

Problem:
I was about to create a script for generating Multiple transactions but the problem is every time the test repeats, there is an element that increments and I was unable to locate that element

Scenario 1: at the first run, this is the value of the element

mouse over  xpath://b
ody/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/**li[1]**/div[1]/img[1]

Scenario 2:
at the second run(repeat the test) this is now the value of the element

mouse over  xpath://body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/**li[2]**/div[1]/img[1]`

*As you can see the tag li[1] from the first scenario becomes li[2] in the second scenario*

Question:
Is there a method or condition where we can put on the test steps if the element/locator changes or increments? so that I'm able to run the repetitive test continuously

Thank you for helping with my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `while` loop combined with `f-strings` to achieve this. Here is how you do it:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

xpath_num = 1
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[{xpath_num}]/div[1]/img[1]')
        xpath_num += 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break #Breaks when element is not found
```

**Edit:**

To implement the same on a `mouseover` method, try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

xpath_num = 1
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[9]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[{xpath_num}]/div[1]/img[1]')
        xpath_num += 1
        hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
        hover.perform()

    except NoSuchElementException:
        break #Breaks when element is not found
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion just a follow up question how can I use this method in the test script like for example

mouse over   then?


#newbie

Comment: I mean where do I put the while loop combined with f-strings that you mentioned?

Should I create another new python file and call it to the test script?

Comment: You can add it in ur main script. Just add all the actions that you wanna perform with the element under the ```try``` block of the code.

Comment: the code is not working there's a warning

Cannot find reference 'find_element_by_xpath' in 'driver.py'

can you give me an example of adding the condition on the mouse over method